# Google Sheets Query Sum Multiple Columns automatically

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a spreadsheet with dynamic columns. I'd like to sum the columns by adding a row. I have found how to sum rows with Query but not columns.

My queries are below and I want to add at the end of each of them the sum of the columns.

```
=
{
INDEX(QUERY(QUERY({Staffs!A2:1000}, 
 "select Col1,"&TEXTJOIN(",", 1, 
 "sum(Col"&SEQUENCE(COUNTA(Staffs!B1:1), 1, 2)&")")&"
  where Col1 is not null 
  group by Col1"), 
 "offset 1", 0));
{" ",ArrayFormula(EDATE(eomonth(Salaries!L1,0),SEQUENCE(1,7*12-MONTH(Salaries!L1)+1,0,1)))};
INDEX(QUERY(QUERY({Salaries!N2:1000}, 
 "select Col1,"&TEXTJOIN(",", 1, 
 "sum(Col"&SEQUENCE(COUNT(TRANSPOSE(Salaries!O2:2)), 1, 2)&")")&"
  where Col1 is not null 
  group by Col1"), 
 "ORDER BY Col1 ASC offset 1", 0))
}
```

The spreadsheet can be viewed there:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1veiYh1CMIfFPwBGQk4OwKmCLa7q08TugReVfAXtpIgI/edit#gid=280688035

Basically I want to calculate the sum for each month for the number of staffs and the salaries

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I start with a summary. Below is a general formula that adds row to any table with numbers and strings on the left (like yours). Then I explain how I got it.

I use name TABLE but it might be any formula that builds a table (query, arrayformula, filter, sequence you name it).

Total for pure numeric table:

```
={TABLE;index(query({TABLE},"Select "&textjoin(",",1,INDEX("sum(Col"&sequence(1,columns(TABLE),1)&")"))),2)}
```

Summary for table with first 1 column with text

```
={TABLE;"",index(query({TABLE},"Select "&textjoin(",",1,INDEX("sum(Col"&sequence(1,columns(TABLE)-1,2)&")"))),2)}
```

Summary for table with first 2 columns with text

```
={TABLE;"","",index(query({TABLE},"Select "&textjoin(",",1,INDEX("sum(Col"&sequence(1,columns(TABLE)-2,3)&")"))),2)}
```

etc.

I've made a first half of the job and I explain how to do the next part. Actually I use the same method as you :-)

First I count columns of the query:

=columns(your query)

Then I use it to build an expression that is used in new query. Generally we need.
=query(your query,"select sum(Col1), sum(Col2)... up to calculated number of columns")

The formula looks like this:

```
=textjoin(",",1,INDEX("sum(Col"&sequence(1,columns(YOUR QUERY HERE)-1,2)&")"))
```

Then I put it under your query using curly brackets.

{your query;
"Sum of month",query(your query,"select sum(Col1), sum(Col2)... up to calculated number of columns")}

Here is my solution:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1WDVM6WVd-JZrLOerysBR0mVzLvBsAKy5ILB58g7rKKY/edit?usp=sharing